# what does it mean "JUMPDEST occupies position 43"

Tags: evm, opcode

I'm looking at the minimal proxy posted by OpenZeppelin([link](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/deep-dive-into-the-minimal-proxy-contract)). I don't know what the text below means.

> The entire set of instructions for this EVM runtime code is made up of
> 45 bytes, and JUMPDEST occupies position 43. In hex, it’s position 2b.
> That’s why, in the specification of the EIP, you’ll see 2b where we’ve
> used dest.

Does that mean that JUMPDEST is located at the 43rd position in many opcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "*Does that mean that `JUMPDEST` is located at the 43rd position in many opcodes*", but what they are saying is that all the EVM instructions that make up the minimal proxy's runtime code, when represented in bytecode, occupy a total of 45 bytes in memory, and in the sequential order `JUMPDEST` is the 43th in the list.

Comment: "43rd position" means the position of memory?